# AngularJS and SailsJS, cancel query when user navigates away from view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sails.js, waterline

I'm working on an application that uses AngularJS for the front end and Sails.js for the back end. There is a search page where users can search for a set of items that match a given criteria. This result can be quite large, so in our query we loop through the data using limit and skip.

We are using the sails-mysql adapter, and are using the Model.query method for now. We may change this to use waterline's built in associations, but not yet. When the user clicks search, the queries from the front end begin like so:

```
for(var i = 0;i < $scope.icount; i = i + $scope.limit){
   $http.get(SAILS_URL + '/details/getItems?i_name=' + $routeParams.item + '&i_version="' + $routeParams.iversion + '&limit=' + $scope.limit + '&skip=' + i, {withCredentials:true})
   .success(function(data) {
        $scope.gridOptions.data.push.apply($scope.gridOptions.data, data);
        numLoaded += $scope.limit;
      });
}
```

The getItems method just gets some URL parameters and the has a Model.query call to get the data from MySQL.

The problem is, when navigating away from the view, the queries, or maybe the loop, continue and can slow down the entire app for that user until they complete. Is there a way to send a signal from the Angular front end to the Sails back end that the user has navigated away from the view and halt the queries? Does angular terminate any running loops when a someone navigates away from a view?

I was suggested to use a listener in sails, something like:

```
req.connection.addListener('close', function () {
    console.log('all done here');
    // callback is fired when connection closed (e.g. closing the browser)
});
```

But we're not sure what to listen for or how to send an event from Angular. Is a listener the way to go? Or is there a better way? Thank you!

Comment: Too broad and too vague. Add some simple illustrative example of what runs where

Comment: Added some details, thanks!